# Iterate through Pandas DataFrame, use condition and add column

Tags: python, pandas

I have purchasing data and want to label them with a new column, which provides information about the daytime of the purchase. For that I'm using the hour of the timestamp column of each purchase.

Labels should work like this:

```
 hour 4 - 7 => 'morning'
 hour 8 - 11 => 'before midday'
 ...
```

I've already picked the hours of the timestamp. Now, I have a DataFrame with 50 mio records which looks as follows.

```
    user_id  timestamp              hour
0   11       2015-08-21 06:42:44    6
1   11       2015-08-20 13:38:58    13
2   11       2015-08-20 13:37:47    13
3   11       2015-08-21 06:59:05    6
4   11       2015-08-20 13:15:21    13
```

At the moment my approach is to use 6x .iterrows(), each with a different condition:

```
for index, row in basket_times[(basket_times['hour']  >= 4) & (basket_times['hour'] < 8)].iterrows():
    basket_times['periode'] = 'morning'
```

then:

```
for index, row in basket_times[(basket_times['hour']  >= 8) & (basket_times['hour'] < 12)].iterrows():
    basket_times['periode'] = 'before midday'
```

and so on.

**However, one of those 6 loops for 50 mio records takes already like an hour. Is there a better way to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function that maps a time period to the string you want, and then use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html).

```
def get_periode(hour):
    if 4 <= hour <= 7:
        return 'morning'
    elif 8 <= hour <= 11:
        return 'before midday'

basket_times['periode'] = basket_times['hour'].map(get_periode)
```

Comment: works perfect! also I figured out, my approach wasn't working at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with boolean masks. I changed `df` for testing:

```
print basket_times
   user_id           timestamp  hour
0       11 2015-08-21 06:42:44     6
1       11 2015-08-20 13:38:58    13
2       11 2015-08-20 09:37:47     9
3       11 2015-08-21 06:59:05     6
4       11 2015-08-20 13:15:21    13

#create boolean masks
morning = (basket_times['hour']  >= 4) & (basket_times['hour'] < 8)
beforemidday = (basket_times['hour']  >= 8) & (basket_times['hour'] < 11)
aftermidday = (basket_times['hour']  >= 11) & (basket_times['hour'] < 15)
print morning
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: hour, dtype: bool

print beforemidday
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: hour, dtype: bool
print aftermidday
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: hour, dtype: bool
```

```
basket_times.loc[morning, 'periode'] = 'morning'
basket_times.loc[beforemidday, 'periode'] = 'before midday'
basket_times.loc[aftermidday, 'periode'] = 'after midday'
print basket_times
   user_id           timestamp  hour        periode
0       11 2015-08-21 06:42:44     6        morning
1       11 2015-08-20 13:38:58    13   after midday
2       11 2015-08-20 09:37:47     9  before midday
3       11 2015-08-21 06:59:05     6        morning
4       11 2015-08-20 13:15:21    13   after midday
```

**Timings** - `len(df) = 500k`:

```
In [87]: %timeit a(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 34 ms per loop

In [88]: %timeit b(df1)
1 loops, best of 3: 490 ms per loop
```

Code for testing:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""user_id;timestamp;hour
11;2015-08-21 06:42:44;6
11;2015-08-20 10:38:58;10
11;2015-08-20 09:37:47;9
11;2015-08-21 06:59:05;6
11;2015-08-20 10:15:21;10"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", index_col=None, parse_dates=[1])
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)
print df.shape
#(500000, 3)
df1 = df.copy()

def a(basket_times):
    morning = (basket_times['hour']  >= 4) & (basket_times['hour'] < 8)
    beforemidday = (basket_times['hour']  >= 8) & (basket_times['hour'] < 11)
    basket_times.loc[morning, 'periode'] = 'morning'
    basket_times.loc[beforemidday, 'periode'] = 'before midday'
    return basket_times

def b(basket_times):
    def get_periode(hour):
        if 4 <= hour <= 7:
            return 'morning'
        elif 8 <= hour <= 11:
            return 'before midday'

    basket_times['periode'] = basket_times['hour'].map(get_periode)
    return basket_times

print a(df)    
print b(df1)
```